# Inserting data to MongoDB in mule with using Database connector (not MongoDBConnector)

Tags: mongodb, mule

I have created database connector with the following configuration.

```
<db:generic-config name="Generic_Database_Configuration"
    url="jdbc:mongodb://localhost:27017/test"   
    driverClassName="mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver"
    doc:name="Generic Database Configuration"/>
```

What will be the query statement to insert following payload to my collection in test database?

```
Payload: {
   _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c),
   title: 'MongoDB Overview', 
   description: 'MongoDB is no sql database',
   by: 'tutorials point',
   url: 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com',
   tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'NoSQL'],
   likes: 100
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
       <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{ _id: ObjectId(7df78ad8902c),
   title: 'MongoDB Overview', 
   description: 'MongoDB is no sql database',
   by: 'tutorials point',
   url: 'http://www.tutorialspoint.com',
   tags: ['mongodb', 'database', 'NoSQL'],
   likes: 100
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <mongo:insert-document config-ref="Mongo_DB__Configuration" collection="COLLECTION_NAME" doc:name="Insert Document"/>
        <mongo:document-to-json doc:name="Document to Json"/>
```

Comment: When I give query as db.errors.insert(#[payload]), I am getting the error java.sql.SQLException: Parse Exception: unity.parser.ParseException: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 1, column 17.

Comment: I'm curious to know if you solved this @MRavindran ?  I'm having a similar problem.